# Migration paths - Mutual with History.SE?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, migration

Now that we're in public, I think we should have migration path close reasons:

- From here to Scifi.SE
- From here to History.SE

Also, it might not be on topic to mention it here, but we should probably have the reverse migration paths as well.

I'm looking for ways to drive traffic here, and having inward migration paths of on topic questions ought to be a good way to do it.

Comment: For scifi? really, better suited with  [hinduism](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/), [buddhism](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/),[christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/), [islam](http://islam.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Migration paths are not set up until a site has become much more established and graduates. Some of the reasons (among others) are outlined here: [Why do we limit migration paths?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203326/98786)

Comment: Thanks for the link. For what it's worth, this was less about "getting rid of off topic stuff" and more about "brainstorming ways to drive traffic here"

Comment: @durron597 I understand. As a side note: before anyone gets the idea of soliciting users to annex content from another site, we don't do that unless that content has been deemed specifically off topic for that site. See **[Respect the community – your own, and others’](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).** I know that's *not* specifically what you were suggesting, but just a heads up because... it happens.

Comment: Thanks! I understand. I'll just have to come up with other ways :)